# General procedure to prove something is a tensor product of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm trying to understand some proofs of statements of the form: Show that some module is the tensor product of two other modules.

When I'm looking at these proofs I always see that they start somewhat like this: Given three $R$-modules $A,B,C$ one wants to show that $A\otimes B\cong C$. An explicit bilinear map $A\times B\longrightarrow C$ is given, i.e. $(a,b)\mapsto c$, and then inferred from the universal property of the tensor product that there exists exactly one $R$-linear map $A\otimes B\longrightarrow C$ where $a\otimes b\mapsto c$. Then an explicit inverse of this last map is given and shown 'by hand' that it is in fact an inverse and $R-$linear. Then the proof ends.

What I don't understand about this approach is why the $A\times B\longrightarrow C$ is given at all. Couldn't one just define the map $A\otimes B\longrightarrow C$ to begin with and show that it is $R$-linear? Why is it easier/necessary to give a bilinear map first and then use the universal property to obtain the second map?

Comment: Perhaps it's not as easy to deal with typical elements of a tensor product as it is to deal with typical elements of a Cartesian product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason why one needs the bilinear map (or multilinear in general), instead of just going ahead to define a map on the tensor product, is that one needs to show that the latter is well-defined. So it may be easy to define some $A \otimes B \rightarrow C$, but it actually may be quite hard to prove that it is well-defined. On the other hand, once a bilinear map $A \times B \rightarrow C$ is established, then the existence of the map on the tensor product simply follows from the universal property, i.e., one does not need to worry if the map is well-defined or not: it is well-defined because it exists.